# how to convert complex json to somthing i can work with in c++

Tags: c++, json, qt, parsing

I'm using qt, and I parse a complex JSON data structure but I find my self doing to many 
loops each time I need to parse this JSON.  What is the best way to parse complex large and complex JSON structures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best C++ JSON parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser)

Answer (score 1):

I use http://qjson.sourceforge.net/ to map JSON data to QVarianMap's. However I don't know how it will work for large data sets.